# how to display default value or field in protocol Buffer 3 running on JAVA

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm currently trying to display or log empty value or default value of a protobuff frame. In my case the protocol buffer is used over an RS232 link , and i need to display default value who are not send in the payload (i know they are implicit) I was thinking first to use the method .hasField(field) but it not adapted due to the length of .proto file.
I have tried to use Json format with a printer
the pointer returned is field with "".

```js
FromSender Message = FromSender.parseFrom(receivedFrame.getPayload());
Printer p = JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields();
String result = p.print(Message);
```

Comment: I finally successful using this  method. I just put the printer inside a method using a builder

Answer (score 1):

I finally successful using this  method. I just put the printer inside a method using a builder

```js
public String getDefaultValue() {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  try {
   if(FrameMessage != null) {
    Printer p = JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields();
    builder.append(p.print(FrameMessage));
   }
  } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
   LOGGER.error("Error while parsing message", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return builder.toString();
  }
```